# How to differentiate keyboards in actionscript 3 or AIR?

Tags: actionscript, air, keyboard

I'm creating a game where the players can use various controllers and keyboards to play. This game is for desktop and it's not used to be played on an internet browser.

Issue: Currently, I am able to detect the key pressed from all the keyboards connected, but there is no way to detect which keyboard pressed it. So in the end result, even if there are several keyboards connected, no one can use the same buttons since pressing a key on a keyboard is like pressing this key on every keyboard.

Looking for: A way to get an ID from the USB device connected that pressed the key so I can track which keyboard is pressing a button or any other way that is able to find out which keyboard has pressed a key.

Comment: You'll need an Adobe Native Extension (ANE) for that - i doubt there are any in existence for such a niche requirement, so you'll probably have to write your own.

Comment: I'm looking into creating an ANE file for this case. A bit more complicated then I though considering the lack of documentation online. If I get it to work, I'll make sure to post it here. Thank you for the info !

Comment: Maybe try to use GameInput class available in air. Still I believe it would only work with game controllers and not distinct keyboards.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/GameInput.html

Also you can take a look here and see if it helps(like getting the keypresses out of it)
https://code.google.com/p/air-hid-usb/